# Hide Tag Title When No Tags

Tags: tags

I'm using this Twig code to display tags on my posts. However, I can't figure out how to get the `Tags:` title to hide itself when there are no tags. If there's no tags, it just shows `Tags: ,` which of course looks ugly.

The code I'm trying below doesn't work and gives me a bunch of errors. Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong?

```
   {% if post.tags_count > 0 %} <span>Tags:
    {% for tag in post.tags %}
        <a href="{{ tag.link }}" class="{{ 'tag-' ~ tag.slug }}">{{ tag.name }}</a>
        {% if not loop.last %}, {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    </span>
   {% endif %}
```

Comment: What are the errors? This seems more about Twig syntax than WP mechanics to me.

Comment: Try `if post.tags` instead of `if post.tags_count > 0`

Comment: For the sake of readability, please properly format your code before adding it to your question. Thanks